# Where is the option to disable iTerm2 confirm window on Log off?

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm

I have MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra. When I try to Log off system I get annyoing confirm dialog each time. Here is it:

[image]

It says that it was prompted because of some option enabled. This option here:
“Prefs > General > Confirm Quit iTerm2”.

What ‘Prefs’ is this about?

I have this in System Preferences > General, and iTerm 2 context menu > Edit Session….

[image]
[image]

Nether System Preferences nor iTerm2 prefs has this checkbox. So how I can disable this confirm dialog on log off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In macOS, you can find the preferences for any app by choosing the app name in the menu bar, then selecting Preferences.

[image]

In this case, the preference being referred to is this one:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That Preference is an iTerm2 preference.

In iTerm2 go to Preferences, choose the General icon. There is a section on Closing this includes `Confirm "Quit iTerm2 (⌘Q)" command`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer! That works perfectly. I will accept answer that was first. It is correct too! Thank you very much